# Firebase query doesn't work with java in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

HEre's my data tree:

```
"look-twopointo": {
"0" {
    "comment": "Hi"
    "Text1": "Hello"
    "Text2": "Bonsoir"
    "type": "Bonjour"
    "version": "4.0.6"
}
}
```

For some reason querying doesn't work.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("0");// pay attention to the this path reference
    // Read from the database
    Query query = mDatabase.child("version")/*.orderByChild("Text1")*/.equalTo("4.0.6")/*.startAt("d")/*.endAt("Dude")*/;
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            //String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); //these three lines below are probably the problem
            String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            System.out.println(value);
            Text.setText(value);
        }
```

I don't know if it's because I'm using my phone and haven't downloaded and tried it on an emulator. Is there something I have to setup so that I can query on my phone? I actually couldn't find an error. It outputs null for NO REASON

Comment: You're the same guy that helped me with that other one. you told me to make a another question in respect of the community guidelines.

Comment: Another question with the other issue **not** with the same issue.

Comment: The issue wasn't solved yet. Feel free to answer it here or on the other one! If you know the solution of course.

Comment: The answer is already in the duplicate and is the exact same as Peter's.

Comment: Peters answer didn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `orderByChild()` with `equalTo()`:

```
Query query = mDatabase.orderByChild("version").equalTo("4.0.6");
```

from the docs:

> [`public Query orderByChild (String path)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#orderByChild(java.lang.String))
>
> Create a query in which child nodes are ordered by the values of the specified path.

Comment: it still doesn't work